# Range of values of C types

Tags: c

In C standard is written that, i.e., an `int` should have:

- min  -32767 max 32767

but in implementation, i.e. on a 16 bit machine that values are:

- min -32768 max 32767

Why do that difference in negative values?

Comment: It depends on whether the platform uses twos or ones complement for negative numbers. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement

Comment: The Standard is allowing for systems where it makes sense to have a negative zero :)

Comment: What the *surprise*! "minimum value for an object of type short int
SHRT_MIN -32767 // −(2^15 − 1)", p.45 of "N1570 Committee Draft — April 12, 2011 ISO/IEC 9899:201x". Nice question for an interview; I'd never gotten that right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both ranges are valid, what is *unusual* is the first one [-32767...32767] but it is perfectly right according to C standard.

In many implementations minimum value for a short integer is `-(2^15 - 1)` then `-32768`. You'll see it defined as:

```
#define SHRT_MIN 0x7FFF
#define SHRT_MIN (-32767 - 1)
#define SHRT_MIN (-32768)
```

Standard asserts that it must be `(-2^15 + 1)` (then `-32767`) **or less** (because *the actual value depends on the particular system and library implementation*). Because most implementations use two's complement to represent negative numbers (when **zero is unsigned for integers**) then minimum negative value is one unit less. In practice it means that you can be sure that when you write your program (regardless of compiler and platform) at least you can store `-32767` in a `short` (but for some compilers/platforms range may be wider as you saw in your compiler).

Please note that in this case `-32768` makes sense (for platforms where `sizeof(int) > sizeof(short)`), not like with `MIN_INT`, because literal value is actually an `int` (not a `short`).

Comment: I'm confused. You say that "it must be... -32767" but then you say "it can be less". That's contradictory.

Comment: @JoeHass you're right, it should be rephrased as "_it must be...or less"_ (as upper bound has to be "_at least_").