# How does C convert signed hex number to negative numbers?

Tags: c, hex, unsigned, signed

So recently, I met this problem:

Given: int x; unsigned int y; x = 0xAB78; y = 0xAB78; write a program to display the decimal values of x and y on the screen.

And here is the program I wrote: ( I am on a 64-bit windows 7 machine)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    short int x;
    unsigned short int y;
    x = 0xAB78;
    y = 0xAB78;
    printf("The decimal values of x and y are: %d & %hu.\n", x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

The output I got is:
x=-21640, and y=43896.

I am ok with the unsigned hex number,
since 0xAB78 = 10*16^3 + 11*16^2 + 7*16^1 + 8*16^0 = 43896.

However for the signed hex number,
should it be: -1*16^3 + 11*16^2 + 7*16^1 +8*16^0 = -1160?
why is it -21640 then?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Imagine that `x` starts at 0, and you have a loop that adds 1. And you go through the loop 43896 times. it will go up to max value (approx 32000), and once it hits max value, when you add one, will go to lowest possible value (approx -32000). Continue through loop (another approx 11000 times) and you will reach -21640. This is a quick explaination of how it works, but I think it would be good if you did more research on variable representations.

Comment: @AntonH: Only for 2s-complement no padding-bits.

Comment: @Deduplicator I was giving the explanation for his compiler, but yes. I was trying to simply explain overflow.

Comment: `A` as a 2s complement leading hex digit is `-6`, not `-1`.  You've calculated the value for (signed short)0xFB78.

Answer (score 0):

If the constant does not fit in your signed integer type, the result is implementation-defined.

C allows 1s-complement, sign-and-magnitude and 2s-complement for signed numbers. Also, `short` has minimum width 16 value-bits and may contain non-value bits. Trap-representations are also possible.

That gives quite a lot of possible results.

For POSIX and Windows machines, 16-bit 2s complement is mandatory, thus just reduce the constant modulo 2**16. If that is >= 2**15, subtract 2**16.

Answer (score 0):

`signed short int` range values is `[-32768 ; 32767]`. Value `0xAB78` (or `43896`) won't fit into, so it overflows into `-32768 + (43896 - 32768)` thus ending in `-21640`.

Comment: Actually, see the surprising question [Range of values of C types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263978/range-of-values-of-c-types) for what the *standard* has to say on the range.